# Jquery list traversal and append: Need to be able to find the anchor in a span then wrap the anchor around the spans inside the parent element

Tags: jquery, append, parent

I am having trouble appending a link to the innerhtml of an elements parent. The content of the link is contained within the element. I am coding this for a content managed site so the users can (and probably will) add random paragraph tags. I have tried to use jquery to formulate my solution but I seem to be missing something (probably glaringly obvious)

Heres the html:

```
<ul class="publications">
    <li>
        <span class="pub-image"><img src="image1.jpg" alt="image1" /></span>
        <span class="description">
            <p><a title="Report1" href="report1.htm">Report1</a></p>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="pub-image"><img src="image2.jpg" alt="image2" /></span>
        <span class="description">
            <p><a title="Report2" href="report2.htm">Report2</a></p>
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="pub-image"><img src="image3.jpg" alt="image3" /></span>
        <span class="description">
            <p><a title="Report3" href="report3.htm">Report3</a></p>
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Ive tried this jquery to find the link inside the span class decription and wrap it around both span elements

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.description').each(function() {
        var itemhref = $(this).find('a').attr("href");
        $(this).parent.html("<a href='"+itemhref+"'>" + $(this).parent.html() + "</a>");

    });
});
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First $(this).parent will throw error as parent is not a function so you should call it like

```
$(this).parent()
```

Second, are you trying to add new paragraph or just anchor ?

If you are trying to append anchor you can do like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.description').each(function() {
        var itemhref = $(this).find('a').clone(true).removeAttr('title');
        $(this).parent().append(itemhref);
    });
  });
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help mprabhat. I was just trying to wrap the link around both the spans in the "li". I dont need a new paragraph. I tried your solution (never thought about clone or parent as a function). Ive ended up with the following HTML <ul class="publications">
    <li>
        <span class="pub-image"><img src="image1.jpg" alt="image1" /></span>
        <span class="description">
            <p><a title="Report1" href="report1.htm">Report1</a></p>
        </span>
    </li>
    <a href="link1">Link1</a>
   
</ul>
If you can suggest a way to wrap the link around the content of the li?

Comment: Tried this and it works. 
'code'
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.description').each(function() {
        var itemhref = $(this).find('a').clone(true).removeAttr('title').text(' ');
  $(this).siblings().wrapInner(itemhref);
    });
  });
'code' 
Is there a more efficient way to do this?